# Format the text within an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have basic text box with an autocomplete that lists the colours of the rainbow, but I'd like to change it so that when you select a colour it comes up in that colour (ie, the word red is coloured red) but I cant figure out how to do it.

Heres the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
      $(function () {
          var colours = [
          "red",
          "orange",
          "yellow",
          "green",
          "blue",
          "indigo",
          "violet",
          ]

          $("#rainbow1").autocomplete({            
              source: colours
          });
      });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="rainbow1" style="color:red">Rainbow1: </label>
  <input type="text"  id="rainbow1" /> </br>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you narrow your code down to your problem and add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks. Well, the code ive posted compiles and runs as it should. Im asking what to add to it to change the colors of the text within the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/gkxe4/1/

```
 $(function () {
     var colours = [
         "red",
         "orange",
         "yellow",
         "green",
         "blue",
         "indigo",
         "violet", ];

     $("#rainbow1").autocomplete({
         source: colours,
         open: function (event, ui) {
             $(".ui-autocomplete li > a").each(function () {
                $(this).css('color', $(this).text());
             });
         },
         select: function (event, ui) {
             alert(ui.item.value);
             $("#rainbow1").css("color", ui.item.value);
         },
         search: function () {
             $(this).css('color', '');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: This works perfectly and exactly how i wanted it to, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do this on blur event....

$("#rainbow1").blur(function() {
 $(this).css('background',$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic example:

```
$("#rainbow1").autocomplete({
    source: colours,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('color', ui.item.value);
    },
    search: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '')
    }
});
```

You need to play with [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) and `search` options of autocomplete.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/eSzyV/

Answer (score 0):

Your autocomplete declaration should contain `select` property. This way you can change color whenever the user selects an item.

```
$("#rainbow1").autocomplete({
    source: colours,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#rainbow1").css("color", ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

View demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qSFdd/).

Docs [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Autocomplete).